# How do I make my nginx load all static files from django docker app over HTTPS?

Tags: python, django, ssl, docker, nginx

I have my nginx installed on the server and I have my Django application running inside a docker container. While my app loads fine over HTTP, it doesn't load any static files (CSS) over HTTPS. What changes should I make in nginx conf or docker app to solve this?

Comment: do you get permission errors? Or any kind of exception in the logs / console?

Comment: There was no errors on the console, it just refused to load css and javascripts when browsed through HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Since my application is in python (Django App), I collected all the static files using "python manage.py collectstatic -c" and then mounted that directory (which contains these static files - /apps/test_app/static ) on the host server running both docker and nginx.

The command I used to mount was

docker run --net=host -v /static:/apps/test_app/static -d -p 8000:8000 image_id

Here static is the directory on the host server where as /apps/test_app/static is directory inside the container.

Once this is done, I added the following lines inside the nginx.conf or ssl.conf file

```
location /static/ {
       # root /var/www/app/static/;
         alias /static/;
         autoindex off;
}
```

Followed by nginx restart and then that solved the problem.